# NULL output with SQL Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

my problem is I received NULL output. What is the problem with my query?

```
$pr_code = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pr_code']);
$counter = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['counter']);

$sql = $mysqli->query("
SELECT 
    a.*,
    b.counter, b.pr pr_b
FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM pr_list) a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT counter, pr
    FROM purchase_request) b 
ON a.pr= b.pr
WHERE a.pr='$pr_code' AND b.counter='$counter'
");

while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $pr= $row['pr'];
  $approved= $row['approved'];
  $requested = $row['requested'];
  }
```

Comment: Why do you use subselects? You can't use select a.* b... from pr_list join purchase_request on ...? You can use left join or right join.

Comment: @krynio I used LEFT JOIN but the output is still NULL

Comment: can you show example data in pr_list and purchase_request?

Comment: Do you have records in pr_list table and purchase_request? Maybe you haven't records for second condition: b.counter='$counter' (maybe b.counter is null)

Comment: Yes I have those table

Comment: Move the WHERE clause's b.counter='$counter' to the ON clause if you really want a LEFT JOIN. (Otherwise it's a regular inner join.)

Comment: See (PHP's) prepared statements

Comment: @jarlh I think that's not the caused of my problem. I try to select on table pr_list only and I get the output that I selected. The problem is what is the problem when I used SQL JOIN

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: When you say the output is null, do you mean you are getting no records or that some of the records returned are null?

Comment: You need to read this link because your query is a bad one in any event even if it returns records. http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Move the WHERE clause's b.counter='$counter' to the ON clause if you really want a LEFT JOIN. (Otherwise it's a regular inner join.)

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("
SELECT 
    a.*,
    b.counter, b.pr pr_b
FROM pr_list a
JOIN purchase_request b 
ON a.pr= b.pr
WHERE a.pr='$pr_code' AND b.counter='$counter'
");
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

This will give you no nulls for purchase_request values.

A left join SPECIFICALLY ALLOWS nulls for b.  So we use an inner join:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("
SELECT 
    a.*,
    b.counter, b.pr pr_b
FROM pr_list a
JOIN purchase_request b 
ON a.pr= b.pr
WHERE a.pr='$pr_code' AND b.counter='$counter'
");
```